# How realistic was the air traffic control mistake by Jane's father?

Tags: breaking-bad, realism

I still do not understand this part of *Breaking Bad* and really hope it was exaggerated. When Jane's father, heavily disturbed by loss of his daughter makes a deadly mistake while guiding air traffic, how would that not be spotted by:

1. The system itself that should be able to calculate projectile.
2. Other dispatchers guiding air traffic in that zone?

Comment: It is possible - see [Überlingen mid-air collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cberlingen_mid-air_collision). However it was a series on unfortunate factors that appeared together (see Other factors in the crash). We can assume something similar happened in the series, but the details were simply not shown.

Comment: This sounds as a reasonable answer, could you turn into one please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event was realistic, [Überlingen mid-air collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cberlingen_mid-air_collision) is a good real-life example. However in this case the reason was not only the mistake of the controller (although it was the main factor), but a series on unfortunate factors that appeared together (see [Other factors in the crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cberlingen_mid-air_collision#Other_factors_in_the_crash)).

One might assume that in case of other similar catastrophes there are also many factors involved and so it was in the show, but the details were simply not shown.